# How to get SSL working on Rails app with Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I am trying to get SSL working on my Rails app that I am deploying with Heroku.

I have used the automated certificate management from Heroku and followed the directions, but when I visit my site I still see a “Not Secure” label in the URL bar. I am trying to figure out how to address this.

My site is at http://give.toacause.com/. When I use inspect in the chrome browser and go to Security, I read that the certificate is missing. However, when I click “view certificate”, I see a notice that “This certificate is valid.”

What step am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though the CNAME record for give.toacause.com is mysterious-bastion-66058.herokuapp.com

You need to use *.herokudns.com.

`heroku domains` will output something like

```
Domain Name                   DNS Record Type  DNS Target
give.toacause.com             CNAME            give.toacause.com.herokudns.com
```

You need to set the CNAME to the value of the DNS target field. After you do, make sure you flush your DNS cache so you can resolve and check it again, or use one of the many HTTPS checkers on the internet.